How to Implement Custom Route Constraints in ASP.NET Core MVC for Complex Scenarios?
In ASP.NET Core MVC, I need to implement custom route constraints to handle complex routing scenarios. Specifically, I want to create a constraint that validates a URL parameter based on a set of business rules. Here are the details:
I want to route requests to different controllers based on a complex URL parameter. For example, if the URL parameter should follow specific business rules or patterns.
The route should only match if the URL parameter meets certain criteria (e.g., follows a specific format or falls within a defined range).
The constraint should be reusable across multiple routes.
The solution should work efficiently and integrate seamlessly with the existing ASP.NET Core routing system.
I've explored built-in constraints and used attribute routing but haven't been able to achieve the required level of flexibility.
ASP.NET Core version: 6.0

Have you checked the IRouteConstraint interface?

To add to what @PeterCsala mentioned

Create a class that implements the IRouteConstraint interface
In your Startup.cs or Program.cs, register the custom constraint in the ConfigureServices
Use the custom constraint in your routes. You can do this either with conventional routing or attribute routing.


Could you please explain more details about which url should be handled and provide some detail example?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
